# How to get the min/max element of nested collections without redundant code using streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

For example:

Given a `Set<Set<Integer>>`, I have tried to use

```
int min = nestedSets.stream().map(s->s.stream().min(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get()).min(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get();
```

My initial idea was to use `flatMap`, however it doesn't returns the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned type should be `OptionalInt` since you don't know it the minimum value is found. You can do:

```
OptionalInt min = nestedSets.stream()
    .flatMap(Set::stream)
    .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
    .min();
```

Alternatively, you can use `Comparator`  with the very same mapping function (`Integer::intValue`) inside `Stream::min` which results in boxed `Optional<Integer>` instead:

```
Optional<Integer> min = nestedSets.stream()
    .flatMap(Set::stream)
    .min(Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::intValue));
```

It depends if you need all these values or just either `min` or `max`.

- **Pros:** I find these solutions easy to read, with no redundant code and the best way to compute min/max/avg or more.
- **Cons:** You can compute only one value (either `min` or `max`) at the same time. Use `IntSummaryStatistics` for summary computations otherwise as already answered here.

Answer (score 2):

You can collect the elements into an [`IntSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html), which is:

> A state object for collecting statistics such as count, min, max, sum, and average.

For example:

```java
Set<Set<Integer>> set = ...;

IntSummaryStatistics stats =
    set.stream()                      // Stream<Set<Integer>>
        .flatMap(Set::stream)         // Stream<Integer>
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)  // IntStream
        .summaryStatistics();         // IntSummaryStatistics

int min = stats.getMin();
int max = stats.getMax();
```

If no values were recorded then `#getMin()` returns `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `#getMax()` returns `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: even funny how we named it `stats` the same :) 1+ to make it even

Answer (score 2):

```
    Set<Set<Integer>> nestedSets = ...

    IntSummaryStatistics stats = nestedSets.stream()
                                           .flatMap(Set::stream)
                                           .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                                           .summaryStatistics();

    stats.getMax();
    stats.getMin();
```